# Plot data from different csv files in one graph using R + ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I have multiple .csv files, every on of this has a column (called: Data) that I want to compare with each other. But first, I have to group the values in a column of each file. In the end I want to have multiple colored "lines" with the mean value of each group in one graph. I will describe the process I use to get the graph I want below. This works for a single file but I don't know how to add multiple "lines" of multiple files in one graph using ggplot.

This is what I got so far:

```
data = read.csv(file="my01data.csv",header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

A single .csv File looks like the following, but without the headline

```
 ID Data Range 
 1,63,5.01   
 2,61,5.02  
 3,65,5.00  
 4,62,4.99
 5,62,4.98  
 6,64,5.01  
 7,71,4.90  
 8,72,4.93  
 9,82,4.89  
10,82,4.80  
11,83,4.82  
10,85,4.79   
11,81,4.80
```

After getting the data I group it with the following lines:

```
data["Group"] <- NA
data[(data$Range>4.95), "Group"] <- 5.0
data[(data$Range>4.85 & data$Range<4.95), "Group"] <- 4.9
data[(data$Range>4.75 & data$Range<4.85), "Group"] <- 4.8
```

The final data looks like this:

```
myTable <- "ID Data Range Group
        1     63   5.01   5.00
        2     61   5.02   5.00
        3     65   5.00   5.00
        4     62   4.99   5.00
        5     62   4.98   5.00
        6     64   5.01   5.00 
        7     71   4.90   4.90
        8     72   4.93   4.90
        9     72   4.89   4.90
       10     82   4.80   4.80
       11     83   4.82   4.80
       10     85   4.79   4.80
       11     81   4.80   4.80"
myData <- read.table(text=myTable, header = TRUE)
```

To plot this dataframe I use the following lines:

```
 ( pplot <- ggplot(data=myDAta, aes(x=myDAta$Group, y=myDAta$Data)) 
  + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", color='red') 
  + xlab("Group") 
  + ylab("Data")
 )
```

Which results in a graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the names of your `.csv`-files stored in a vector named `file_names`. Then you can run the following code and should get a different line for each file:

```
library(ggplot2)
data_list <- lapply(file_names, read.csv , header=FALSE, sep=",")

data_list <- lapply(seq_along(data_list), function(i){
  df <- data_list[[i]]
  df$Group <- round(df$Range, 1)
  df$DataNumber <- i
  df
  })

finalTable <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
finalTable$DataNumber <- factor(finalTable$DataNumber)

ggplot(finalTable, aes(x=Group, y=Data, group = DataNumber, color = DataNumber)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
  xlab("Group") + 
  ylab("Data")
```

**How it works**
First the different datasets are read with `read.csv` into a list `data_list`. Then each `data.frame` in that `list` is assigned a Group. 
I used `round` here with `k=1`, which means it rounds to one decimal point (I figured that's what your are doing).
Then also a unique number (in this case simply the index of the list) is assigned to each `data.frame`. After that the `list` is combined to one `data.frame` with `rbind` and then DataNumber is turned into a `factor` (prettier for plotting). Finally I added DataNumber as a group and color variable to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I appreciate your explanation below your solution! Sadly I do not have my .csv-files stored in a vector. Would you be so kind to tell me how to save them in one?

Comment: You need the names of the csv - files in a vector. For example: `file_names <- c("my01data.csv", "my02data.csv", "my03data.csv")`

Comment: I think that I have not fully understood the lapply() function, because I wanted to use it to add the column names to every file. data_list <- lapply(data_list, colnames(data_list) <-c("ID", "Data", "Range"))

Comment: `data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(df) colnames(df) <-c("ID", "Data", "Range")) ` should work. See also this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/5892059) for a great introduction to the lapply-family

Comment: Thank you again!
Now I get the following error: Error in df$Range : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: When adding the different files, is it okay to add the absolute path instead of just the name, like:
file_names <- c("~Files/Results/01data.csv", "~Files/Results/02data.csv")

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You have to add that you want to have df as a return value so data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(df){ colnames(df) <-c("ID", "Data"); df})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170789/discussion-between-kath-and-schande).

Answer (score 0):

You can add another line by using `stat_summary` again; you can define the `data` and `aes` argument to any other dataset:

```
#some pseudo data for testing
my_other_data <- myData 
my_other_data$Data <- my_other_data$Data * 0.5 

pplot <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Group, y=Data)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", color='red') +
    stat_summary(data=my_other_data, aes(x=Group, y=Data), 
           fun.y = mean, geom = "line", color='green') +
    xlab("Group") +
    ylab("Data")
pplot
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a classifying column ("Class")

```
myTable1$Class <- "table1"

myTable1 
   "ID Data Range Group Class
    1     63   5.01   5.00    table1
    2     61   5.02   5.00    table1
    3     65   5.00   5.00    table1"

myTable2$Class <- "table2"

myTable2 
    "ID Data Range Group Class
    1     63   5.01   5.00    table2
    2     61   5.02   5.00    table2
    3     65   5.00   5.00    table2"
```

And merging dataframe

```
dfBIND <- rbind(myTable1, MyTable2)
```

So that you can ggplot with a grouping or coloring variable

```
pplot <- ggplot(data=dfBIND, aes(x= dfBIND$Group, y= dfBIND$Data, group=Class)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", color='red') +
xlab("Group") +
ylab("Data")
```